# is it ok to deploy an older version of your rails app to heroku not doing a rollback?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

If you deploy v.15 to heroku which was inside your C:/app folder, but it is causing unforeseen issues. Can you just go through the typical deploy using `git add .` `git add -u` `git commit -m "older"`etc on an older version to deploy v.13 that you backed up a few days ago?

In this v.15 deploy, there was a new table creation - > heroku rake db:migrate as well

I'm trying to get my app working again so I want to be cautious

Answer (score 0):

Yes. As long as it is a normal commit in the history of the repo, it should be just fine. That said, a better method to accomplish what you're trying to do might be to use git's cherry-pick functionality.

If you're unsure, you may wish to create a second application. You can use the new `heroku fork` feature (new as of v2.36 of the Toolbelt - use `heroku help fork` to get more info about it) in order to clone your app into a new app. This is a great way to creating a staging environment from an existing app.

You could use this to see how deploying your new (old?) changes would work. Hope that helps!